# Centering a Shortcode from PageBuilder in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I want the content from the pagebuilder to be centered on the page, instead of flush left like shown in the link.

Any ideas?

http://sbserver.wwwsd3.a2hosting.com/devo_williams_freshcafe/franchising-step-1/

Comment: You center it with some css or create a new shortcode in your `functions.php` file (or separate file) to fill your needs.

Comment: I tried using some CSS, but it is not taking.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried, and we will try to help you from there ?

Comment: I'm adding this right in the page:

<div style="margin:0 auto !important;">[template id="1141"]</div>

Comment: In order to center a div with margin, you need to apply a width to it.